# jQuery Selectors - selecting the right <h4> tag

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to use jQuery to grab the `<h4>` tag that is closes to a link the user clicked. So from the sample code below, if someone clicks on the "BUY ONLINE" link under the Product 2 heading, I want to use jQuery to grab the text of this `<h4>` tag, which is "Product 2".

I have tried the following but it will always only give me "product 1" as the value despite which link is clicked:

```
$(".products h4").first().text();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="products">
<h4>Product 1 Title</h4>
<p>Product 1 description</p>
<div class="buyatdealer">
<a class="buynow" href="buy/product1"><span>BUY ONLINE</span></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="products">
<h4>Product 2 Title</h4>
<p>Product 2 description</p>
<div class="buyatdealer">
<a class="buynow" href="buy/product2"><span>BUY ONLINE</span></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="products">
<h4>Product 3 Title</h4>
<p>Product 3 description</p>
<div class="buyatdealer">
<a class="buynow" href="buy/product3"><span>BUY ONLINE</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `first()` will always select the first `h4`.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's tree traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 4):

Asuming you are on the click function and clicked the `a`.

```
$(this).closest(".products").find('h4').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

many ways to get it..

fews are..

using `parents()`

```
 $('.products a span').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.products').find('h4').text());
});
```

using `closest()`.

```
$('.products a span').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.products').find('h4').text());
});
```

using `siblings()`

```
$('.products a span').click(function(){
alert($(this).parents('.buyatdealer').siblings('h4').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to re-think the problem you're trying to solve, and then the solution.

What happens when someone clicks "BUY ONLINE" that you need the text for? Are you using it for presentation, or is this part of the actual purchase process, sent off to the backend (or something similar)?

Trusting the text in an `h4` closest to a "BUY ONLINE" button seems error-prone.

As an alternative to this DOM traversal and strange coupling, could you instead set a data-attribute on the "BUY ONLINE" button?

```
<span data-product-id="0" data-product-name="Product One">BUY ONLINE</span>
```

... or even better ...

```
<button data-product-id="0" data-product-name="Product One">BUY ONLINE</button>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

$(this).closest(".products h4").text(); would get you that text, assuming you always keep the h4 tag as a child of .products.